# How to remove blank space in column head in SQL

Tags: sql

This is my SQL query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
         CAST(Set_Weight as decimal(38,2)) AS Set_Weight,
         Material_Code
     FROM Consumption_Report) AS t1 
PIVOT
    (SUM(Set_Weight) 
         FOR Material_Code IN ([GREEN ACID], [INVAZYME AST], [PRIMAFAST LUNA CL], [ULTRAOVEN CPR])
    ) AS PivotTable
```

Result is

| GREEN ACID | INVAZYME AST | PRIMAFAST LUNA CL | ULTRAOVEN CPR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

I want to remove the blank space from headers

| GREENACID | INVAZYMEAST | PRIMAFASTLUNACL | ULTRAOVENCPR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

Comment: don't do select *, name the fields and add aliases without spaces

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use aliases;

```
SELECT
    [GREEN ACID] AS GREENACID,[INVAZYME AST] AS INVAZYMEAST,
    [PRIMAFAST LUNA CL] AS PRIMAFASTLUNACL,[ULTRAOVEN CPR] AS ULTRAOVENCPR
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CAST(Set_Weight as decimal(38,2)) AS Set_Weight,
        Material_Code
    FROM Consumption_Report
) AS t1 
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Set_Weight) FOR Material_Code
    IN ([GREEN ACID],[INVAZYME AST],[PRIMAFAST LUNA CL],[ULTRAOVEN CPR])
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Please just use column aliases.

```
SELECT
    [GREEN ACID] GREENACID, [INVAZYME AST] INVAZYMEAST, [PRIMAFAST LUNA CL] PRIMAFASTLUNACL,    [ULTRAOVEN CPR] ULTRAOVENCPR
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CAST(Set_Weight as decimal(38,2)) AS Set_Weight,
        Material_Code
    FROM Consumption_Report
) AS t1 
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Set_Weight) FOR Material_Code
    IN ([GREEN ACID],[INVAZYME AST],[PRIMAFAST LUNA CL],[ULTRAOVEN CPR])
) AS PivotTable
```